# unicode characters are not displayed when requestdispatcher.forward is used to redirect to a page

Tags: servlets, internationalization, utf, requestdispatcher

I my creating an application which supports English and Japanese languages. I'm using resource bundle and property files.

Problem is occuring when I use request dispacther to forward the request to another JSP file:

```
  RequestDispatcher rd1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp/Update.jsp");
  rd1.forward(request, response);
```

The japanese characters are displayed as

> ????

But, when I directly open Update.jsp by providing complete path, the japanese characters are displayed as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a JSP page is a HTML page with Java content inside of it.

Have you included the japanese character set in the JSP?

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-JP" >
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-JP" %>
```

If this doesn't work, try doing this:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

before you forward the request

Comment: yes i have  used the problem is occuring only when i use requestdispatcher instead if i use windows.loction in javascript to redirect to update.jsp it is working just fine

Comment: Can you provide an example structure of your JSPs? To see if the structure is messing something up when using RequestDispatcher

Comment: Reading from other StackOverflow's questions, it seems like the encoding should be the same for all files.

Comment: Maybe this is not the best practice, but you could try having two separate JSPs (one with the japanese encoding in the META tag or using <% @page %> directive; and another one for the english version; forward to the japanese one if the user has selected japanese version, and viceversa? It's the only idea that occurs to me

Comment: response.setContentType("text/html");